# fscanf padding with 0 with new lines

Tags: c

I am having trouble reading in a control file with multiple new lines at the end.

```
    void readControlFromFile (FILE *f)
    {   
    int N = 100;
    controlData = (ControlEntry **)malloc(sizeof(ControlEntry *) * N);
    char line [10];
    controlData[0] = (ControlEntry *)malloc(sizeof(ControlEntry));
    fscanf (f, "%d %d %d", &controlData[0]->occurance, &controlData[0]->text, &controlData[0]->pattern);
    while(fgets(line, 10, f) != NULL)
    {
        controlData[lineCount] = (ControlEntry *)malloc(sizeof(ControlEntry));
        fscanf (f, "%d %d %d", &controlData[lineCount]->occurance, &controlData[lineCount]->text, &controlData[lineCount]->pattern);
        //printf("%d %d %d \n", controlData[lineCount]->occurance, controlData[lineCount]->text, controlData[lineCount]->pattern);
        lineCount++;

        if(lineCount == N)
        {
            N*=2;
            controlData = (ControlEntry **)realloc(controlData, sizeof(ControlEntry *) * N);
        }
    }


}
```

The fscanf seems to put default values of 0 into the buffer, and I have tried a break as follows:

```
if(line[0] == '\n')
{
 break;
}
```

But to no avail. I am aware this will be a simple fix, but I am a bit new with C.

Thanks

Comment: Please show some failing input.

Comment: shouldn't you be using `sscanf` instead of `fscanf`?

Comment: Could you test the return value of `fscanf` ? Is it 3 ? If it's not 3, how much is it ? Could you print the error message `perror ("The following error occurred");` ?

Answer (score 0):

You must check the return value of fscanf (or any other *scanf).  It will tell  you how many tokens were read.